# View Binding in DialogFragment with custom layout in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I loved using Kotlin synthetic for its simplicity and code elegance but now they made it depricated and push you to use those ugly view bindings.

There are plenty of answers on how to use it in activites and Fragments, but could not find any examples for custom layout alert dialogs.

Here is the code which worked perfectly with Kontlin synthetic.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_reward.*

class RewardDialog: DialogFragment() {
    private var mView: View? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return mView
    }
    
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            mView = it.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_reward, null)
            AlertDialog.Builder(it).apply {
                setView(mView)
            }.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        //reference layout elements by name freely
        
    }
    
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mView = null
    }
}
```

How do I migrate this to view bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have ended up with the following solution. Thanks to @Kishan Maurya for the hint about `binding.root`.

```
private var _binding: DialogRewardBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.run {
        //initiate the binding here and pass the root to the dialog view
        _binding = DialogRewardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            //reference layout elements by name freely here
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
            setView(binding.root)
        }.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}


override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use generated `ViewBinding` views here and not use `onCreateDialog`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RewardDialog : DialogFragment() {
private var binding: DialogRewardBinding by autoCleared()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_Dialog_MinWidth)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    binding = DialogRewardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    //reference layout elements by name freely
    binding.tvReward.setOnClickListener { }
   }

}
```

`autoCleared()` is an extension function which will null out all the view in `onDestroy()` taken from [google's architecture component sample here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/9826b59956eb93c9e627bdf16a19a1c8bc28ce14/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/AutoClearedValue.kt)

You can set `R.style.Theme_MaterialComponents_Light_Dialog_MinWidth` theme in `onCreate()` so that DialogFragment follows the minWidth defined in Material Compnent theme on deferent screen sizes just like `AlertDialog`

Edit:

If you are not using the material component library then you can set the width in `onViewCreated()` using the Kotlin extension.

```
 setWidthPercent(ResourcesCompat.getFloat(resources, R.dimen.dialogWidthPercent).toInt())
```

Kotlin extenstion function

```
fun DialogFragment.setWidthPercent(percentage: Int) {
val percent = percentage.toFloat() / 100
val displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
val rect = displayMetrics.run { Rect(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels) }
val percentWidth = rect.width() * percent
dialog?.window?.setLayout(percentWidth.toInt(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

}
```

Comment: Does this solution require material components added to the project?

Comment: @yaugenka Yes. You can use AppCompact, or you can use a Kotlin function which will set the dialogWindow's width at runtime.

Comment: I'm not using the material components and prefer using the alert dialog builder instead of messing with the dialog?.window?.setLayout call.

Comment: @yaugenka look into `windowFixedWidthMajor` or `windowFixedWidthMinor`

Comment: Setting a style here is not good, because it resets all style customizations to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RewardDialog : DialogFragment() {

    private var mView: View? = null
    private lateinit var dialogBinding: DialogRewardBinding

    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // either this way we can init dialogBinding
        dialogBinding = DialogRewardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return dialogBinding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            // either this way we can init dialogBinding
            dialogBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(it, R.layout.dialog_reward)
            AlertDialog.Builder(it).apply { setView(mView) }.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        with(view) {
            myText.text = "Demo"
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mView = null
    }
}
```

instead of `mView`, you can use `dialogBinding.root`

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="demo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: onCreateView is expected to return a null-type value but binding.root is not-null type.

Comment: is this causing problem? It's expecting null type but if we are passing not null type then it would not be a problem.

Comment: if it gives a warning then there is something wrong with this

Comment: This is the wrong way to use ViewBinding. using DataBindingUtil to solve another problem is what creating OP problems. @yaugenka Any specific reason you are using alert dialog builder here ?

Comment: @SomeshKumar, I want it to look like AlertDialog and don't mess with dialog!!.window?.setLayout manually

Comment: @yaugenka that you can achieve by settings a material style to your dialog. If you want I can post a full answer.